# How to introduce using or namespace in C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am noob in C#. I used to `import` classes in Java, and Eclipse always helped and prompted .

In C# I was trying to upload a document to sharepoint and tried to use example from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/602369/C-23pluscodeplustoplusuploadplusdocumentplustoplus)

I made a reference to `http....../lists.asmx` and called it `ServiceWebReference`

However the following lines got underlined in red by Visual Studio

```
ServiceWebReference.Lists listService = new ServiceWebReference.Lists();
```

It does not recognize `ServiceWebReference` . So How do I `import` this class . I have added a refernce , isn't it enough ?

As a general case , when C# requests me to explicitly provide a namespace , how can I figure out what `using` statement to use ? Visual Studio does not prompt anything, doesn't it ?

I tried right click and look for `Resolve` but it is not there 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference with the class in it, right click the text of the class then Resolve-> then a using statement or a fully qualified statement can be selected.

Comment: +1 Thank you . I tried right click , but `Resolve` did not show up .

Comment: @Donotello You shouldn't upvote answers that don't help you solve your problem.  In fact, if an answer isn't helpful you should generally *downvote* it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can right click the item and choose `Resolve - Using XXX`.

Or use a utility like [`Resharper`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) that will prompt you to add the correct using statement.

Comment: +1 Thank you . I tried right click , but `Resolve` did not show up . Also , `Reshaper` is an extension . And I am not allowed to install it

Answer (score 1):

You could first make sure that "show all files" is on in the solution explorer and then open the node containing the web reference. There should be a C# file there svcmap or similar which contains the proxy code. Examine that file, it contains all the information on namespaces and types you need.

The object explorer is another quick way to browse the types in the solution.